# What would be the best way to pass a list from python to js using bottle?

Tags: javascript, python, string, escaping, bottle

I am using Bottle as a web server and need to pass a python list to javascript.

When I am doing just {{myList}}, Bottle escapes single quotes for strings in the list and shows them as `&#039;`
JS, in turn, isn't very happy with what it gets.

I managed to find a solution, but I don't think it's an optimal one.

```
var tempList = '{{eval(myList)}}'.replace(/&#039;/g, "'");
var myNewList = eval(tempList);
```

I wonder, is there a better way to do this?

**upd:** I moved the solution I found into the 'Answers' section.

Comment: If your question is resolved, please either accept the answer that helped you most, or write your own answer which you will be able to accept as well. Please refrain from posting your own answer in an update to the question.

Comment: Also, `json` in python 3 *is* the simplejson module, which was integrated into the python standard library some time ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I started using json (json_dumps in Python3, simplejson won't install), but bottle was still escaping single quotes. I found in Bottle manual that you can skip escaping using the exclamation sign and changed my code:

```
var myNewList = {{!myList}};
```

Comment: Just found out that json_dumps actually looks this way because it is imported to Bottle this way. Just in Python 3 it will still be json.dumps

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`json` module](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) instead; it outputs valid JavaScript expressions after all.

> JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a subset of JavaScript syntax (ECMA-262 3rd edition) […]

Quick example:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps([1, 2, 'foo', 'bar'])
'[1, 2, "foo", "bar"]'
```

Put that straight into your template. I use this all the time to put valid JavaScript data structures into my generated web pages all the time.

Comment: JSON is not a valid JavaScript data structure. You should parse JSON string to create the list in JavaScript: `var yourList = JSON.parse({{yourJSONString}});`

Comment: @iurisilvio: give me an example of a JSON string that *isn't* valid JavaScript. I don't count the [U+2028 or a U+2029 characters](http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset/) as enough, as the python `json` module escapes those using the `\u` notation.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Bottle, but I do have the same problem when using Django. My solution is dump the Python list to JSON format. Javascript is happy with JSON.

```
myList = [1, 2, 3, 'string', "&apm;", '"']
```

Then return `simplejson.dumps(myList)` to your web pages.
In js:

```
var myList = <dumped-literal-JSON-string>
```

NOTE: DO NOT surround the dumpped JSON value with quotes.