# Escape strings for JavaScript using Jinja2?

Tags: javascript, python, jinja2

How do I escape HTML with Jinja2 so that it can be used as a string in JavaScript (jQuery)?

If I were using Django's templating system I could write:

```
$("#mydiv").append("{{ html_string|escapejs }}");
```

Django's [`|escapejs` filter](https://github.com/django/django/blob/ebc773ada3e4f40cf5084268387b873d7fe22e8b/django/utils/html.py#L63) would escape things in `html_string` (eg quotes, special chars) that could break the intended use of this code block, but Jinja2 does not seem to have an equivalent filter (am I wrong here?).

Is there a cleaner solution than copying/pasting the code from Django?

Comment: See here: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#escaping

Comment: I don't need to escape the jinja tag text itself, I need to ensure that `html_string` doesn't contain any harmful chars.

Comment: Maybe the |safe filter is what you are after than: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/templating/#standard-filters

Comment: possible duplicate of [What would be the best way to pass a list from python to js using bottle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11427417/what-would-be-the-best-way-to-pass-a-list-from-python-to-js-using-bottle)

Comment: @MartijnPieters The solution is similar, but the question was ultimately meant for pywebkitgtk, not bottle... As the answers in that question relate to that framework, I don't believe this is a duplicate.

Comment: @meshy: The exact same principle applies though. Incorporate JavaScript literals by using the `json.dumps()` function.

Comment: Jinja has a [builtin `tojson` filter now](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/templating/#standard-filters). This seems to dump it out as a JS-escaped string, not a proper JSON object, so you'll need to call `var my_data = JSON.parse({{ my_string|tojson }})`

Comment: @MartijnPieters Actually, now (since version 2.9) there are solutions native to jinja2 (tojson filter).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I faced a similar problem last year.  Not sure whether you're using [bottle](http://bottlepy.org), but my solution looked something like this.

```
import json

def escapejs(val):
    return json.dumps(str(val)) # *but see [Important Note] below to be safe

@app.route('/foo')
def foo():
    return bottle.jinja2_template('foo', template_settings={'filters': {'escapejs': escapejs}})
```

(I wrapped the `template_settings` dict in a helper function since I used it everywhere, but I kept it simple in this example.)

Unfortunately, it's not as simple as a builtin jinja2 filter, but I was able to live with it happily--especially considering that I had several other custom filters to add, too.

*Important Note*: Hat tip to @medmunds's for his astute comment below, reminding us that json.dumps is not XSS-safe.  IOW, you wouldn't want to use it in a production, internet-facing server.  Recommendation is to write a [safer json escape routine](https://github.com/dsissitka/khan-website/blob/master/templatefilters.py#L112-139) (or steal django's--sorry OP, I know you were hoping to avoid that) and call that instead of using json.dumps.

Comment: Perfect! I'm not using bottle, I'm using pywebkitgtk to build a desktop app, but `json.dumps` is exactly what I needed. Much simpler than I'd hoped! Thank-you!

Comment: Oh, and thanks for the link to bottle! I've not seen that before, could come in handy ;)

Comment: I don't think json.dumps() escapes everything you need to worry about. E.g., as currently written, `escapejs("</script>")` returns `"</script>"` -- which seems like it could allow a closing script tag (and anything after it!) to leak into your html. (The Django escapejs filter does unicode escapes on the < and > characters, which avoids the problem.)

Comment: ... yeah, seems like this answer definitely leaves an XSS vulnerability. Khan Academy [has some examples here](https://sites.google.com/a/khanacademy.org/forge/technical/autoescape-in-jinja2-templates) and provides their own escapejs and jsonify filters. Looks like they borrowed [their implementation of escapejs](https://github.com/dsissitka/khan-website/blob/master/templatefilters.py#L112-139) from Django.

Comment: @medmunds, thanks for pointing out the XSS vulnerability.  You're right; I'll update the entry to point that out.  (FWIW, in my case my service is internal, behind firewall, so XSS attack was not a top concern.  I'll fix my code nevertheless, just to get in the right habit.)

Answer (score 23):

Jinja2 has nice filter [tojson](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#tojson). If you make json from string, it will generate string enclosed in double quotes "". You can safely use it in javascript. And you don't need put quotes around by yourself.

```
$("#mydiv").append({{ html_string|tojson }});
```

It also escapes `<>&` symbols. So it is safe even when sting contains something XSS dangerous like `<script>`

Answer (score 15):

This is a `escapejs` filter, based on Django's one, that I wrote for use in Jinja2 templates:

```
_js_escapes = {
        '\\': '\\u005C',
        '\'': '\\u0027',
        '"': '\\u0022',
        '>': '\\u003E',
        '<': '\\u003C',
        '&': '\\u0026',
        '=': '\\u003D',
        '-': '\\u002D',
        ';': '\\u003B',
        u'\u2028': '\\u2028',
        u'\u2029': '\\u2029'
}
# Escape every ASCII character with a value less than 32.
_js_escapes.update(('%c' % z, '\\u%04X' % z) for z in xrange(32))
def jinja2_escapejs_filter(value):
        retval = []
        for letter in value:
                if _js_escapes.has_key(letter):
                        retval.append(_js_escapes[letter])
                else:
                        retval.append(letter)

        return jinja2.Markup("".join(retval))
JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.filters['escapejs'] = jinja2_escapejs_filter
```

Example safe usage in a template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var variableName = "{{ variableName | escapejs }}";
…
//-->
</script>
```

When variableName is a `str` or `unicode`.

Comment: It is already required that `{{ variableName | espacejs }}` is in quotes (single or double) so square brackets tricks are not possible. Otherwise even a space could be dangerous.

Comment: This answer helped me out in this thread. Real mind bender to escape characters inside a string that are going to be printed from Python to HTML which is going to be inside quote tags inside JavaScript which is going to parse as JSON. Thnx for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I just researched this problem, my solution is to define a filter:

```
from flask import Flask, Markup
app = Flask(__name__)
app.jinja_env.filters['json'] = lambda v: Markup(json.dumps(v))
```

and in the template:

```
<script>
var myvar = {{myvar|json}} ;
</script>
```

This has the nice feature that *myvar* can be anything that can be JSON-serialised

Comment: Don't do this with user-generated content, as users will be able to execute JS. For example when `myvar` = `</script><script>alert('XSS');`

Answer (score 0):

Based on @tometzky here is my Python 3 version:

```py
_js_escapes = {
        '\\': '\\u005C',
        '\'': '\\u0027',
        '"': '\\u0022',
        '>': '\\u003E',
        '<': '\\u003C',
        '&': '\\u0026',
        '=': '\\u003D',
        '-': '\\u002D',
        ';': '\\u003B',
        u'\u2028': '\\u2028',
        u'\u2029': '\\u2029'
}
# Escape every ASCII character with a value less than 32.
_js_escapes.update(('%c' % z, '\\u%04X' % z) for z in range(32))

@register.filter
def escapejs(value):
    return jinja2.Markup("".join(_js_escapes.get(l, l) for l in value))
```

The usage is exactly the same.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use jinja2's `autoescape`. So, for instance, you could add autoescape to your jinja2 Environment in Python:

```
JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
    autoescape=True)
```

Alternatively, you could use the Autoescape Extension added in Jinja 2.4 to have more control over where the autoescaping is used in the HTML. More information on this [here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#autoescaping) and example (in Google App Engine) [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/templates).

Python:

```
JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
    extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'])
```

HTML:

```
{% autoescape true %}
    <html>
        <body>
            {{ IWillBeEscaped }}
        </body>
    </html>
{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: Isn't this just standard HTML escaping?  The question asks about Javascript?

Comment: Nope, that definitely HTML escaping only.